# PHP - iPhone send full URL into REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, iphone, facebook, router

I have a problem with my router. It is producing many Error404 because of invalid variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Normally REQUEST_URI is in format `/your-event/buy/` but in logs it always contains full URL like `http://domain.com:80/your-event/buy/` and if there is this, REFERRER is always `http://m.facebook.com` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is iPhone

Is it bug of router or what? I can see many orders made on iPhone, but also lots of those errors in log. I think that `REQUEST_URI` should't contains whole URL. Btw, I'm using really simple AltoRouter (http://altorouter.com/)

Comment: "It is producing many Error404 because of invalid variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']"  Can you post the actual error that is generated and where you see the error?  Also, what are you using with AltoRouter -- Apache/nginx?  Post the relevant config of that service too.

Comment: It produce Error404 cause AltoRouter `match` return false. It works for 99% of traffic, but there are also those invalid ones. As it works mostly fine, I'm thinking if that REQUEST_URI can contains full URL or not..

Answer (score 0):

`http://domain.com:80` is nothing but website running in port 80 since it is http request and `http://domain.com:443` if url refers to https

and

`http://domain.com:80` and `http://domain.com` both are same, you can use `https://www.google.com:443` or simply https://www.google.com

Comment: Yeah.. But PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable shouldn't contain full address..

Comment: check this variable     $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']